# Express-validator. validation schema with equals property

Tags: node.js

i have a problem with express validator. I cann not understand how to create validation schema with property equals. 
I want to validate a password. my form has "password" and "conf-password". 
who knows how to test their equality? thanks.

Comment: How about `password === conf-password`

Comment: No, i need some one like this

'password': {
            equals: {
                options: ['conf-password', 'password'],
                errorMessage: "Invalid password confirmation"
            }
        }

but this not working

Comment: Can you provide link to the validator library you use?

Comment: https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

Comment: Try `'password': {matches:{options:[req.<params or body or query>.con-password]}, errorMessage....}` this assumes the validation schema has access to req object. **What I would suggest is to check for the equality on client-side before you even send it to server.**

Comment: thanks, it hepled me) 

but i think my code is not good. i am create a method at a model of the user which returns a validation schema. and now if i want to validate a form i must do like this: 
var validation = require('modules/validator')(req, user.validationSchema(req));

variable "validation" = true or consists of errors array. 
what do you think about this validation way?

Comment: thus validation for any model is it the same

Comment: I would probably add methods for validation to models so in mongoose for example I would use `User.validate(req);` or something similar. This way you don't need to require anything since the function is already part of model you use, assuming that you validate the input and save data to db

Comment: thank you) i think that i wiil do as you say)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but I used this in a schema and it works for me:

```
check_pwd : { errorMessage: 'Confirm new pass', equals: { options: [req.body.new_pwd] }, trim : true }
```